# Minimal embedding for blowing ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, projective-varieties

Let us consider the following specific problem for blowing-ups.

Let $n$ be a large positive integer. Let $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a smooth sub variety of codimension $>1$. Denote $Y$ the blowing-up of $\mathbb P^n$ along $X$. I would like to inject $Y$ into $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ (thus as a hyper surface). Is it something possible ? If not, what could be the minimal $N$ (depending on $n$ and $X$ of course) such that $Y$ can be embedded into $\mathbb P^N$ ?

Ideas, examples and references are welcome !
Thanks in advance.

p.s. By saying that $n$ is large, I mean that I wish to have results for $n$ as large as possible. But I do not even know if the value of $n$ is really important in this question. One may wish to restrict to complex projective varieties to fix ideas.

Comment: The first request (embedding $Y$ as a hypersurface) is not possible. When $n$ is at least 3, a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbf P^{n+1}$ has Picard number 1, but a blowup has Picard number $>1$. I don't have a good answer to the more general question about the minimal value of $N$ that admits an embedding.

Comment: In general the best you can get is $N=2n+1$. Every smooth $n$ dimensional variety embeds in $2n+1$ dimensional projective space.

Comment: @Mohan Thank. You are right. And also, as Lazzaro said, $N$ has also to be larger than $2n-2$, since by a Barth type theorem, if $N\leq 2n-2$, then $\mathrm{Pic}(Y)=\mathbb Z$, while a blow up has Picard number $>1$. So the best embedding can only be $2n-1$, $2n$ or $2n+1$. The Barth type theorem I was using is : Let $Y\subset \mathbb P^N$ be a smooth subvariety of dimension $r$. If $r\geq (N+2)/2$, then $Y$ is of Picard number $1$. Note that $Y$ may not be a complete intersection and in this latter case one may have better results due to Lefschetz Hyperplane section theorem.